# proving properties of $\Bbb N$ after constructing it as a subset of $\Bbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, induction, natural-numbers

Working through Schröder Mathematical Analysis right now. Assuming existence & uniqueness of $\Bbb R$ (as complete ordered field), the text is now trying to prove the various properties of $\Bbb N$ understood as the unique subset of $\Bbb R$ satisfying the following:

(i) $\Bbb N$ is a successor set (i.e. $1 \in \Bbb N$ and $n \in \Bbb N \implies n+1 \in \Bbb N$), and

(ii) For $S$ any successor set, $S \subseteq \Bbb N \implies S = \Bbb N$.

Is it possible from here to prove the following fact about the natural numbers (Prop. 1.25 in Schröder)?

$$(\forall m,n \in \Bbb N) \space n < m \implies  m - n \in \Bbb N $$

So far the only other property of $\Bbb N$ proven is that it is closed under addition and multiplication. The proof outlined in the text has two parts:

1. Step one is to prove that $(\forall m \in \Bbb N) \space m - 1 \in \Bbb N \space \text{or} \space m = 1$. No problems here.
2. For step two, the idea is to define $S := \{ n \in \Bbb N \space:\space (\forall m \in \Bbb N)\space n<m \implies m-n \in \Bbb N \} \subseteq \Bbb N$, prove that this is a successor set as defined above, and then use $S \subseteq \Bbb N$ and the Principle of Induction ((ii) above) to force equality.

It gets really gritty but I believe there's a case that isn't considered in the text's proof: it's easy enough to show that $1 \in S$, but then in showing that $n \in S \implies n+1 \in S$, letting $n \in S$, then letting $m \in \Bbb N$ with $(n+1) < m$, you have to consider two cases: either $m - 1 \in \Bbb N$ or $ m = 1$. The first case presents no problems, but I can't see how to proceed for the case where $m = 1$. Taking $m = 1$, it boils down to needed to prove that $n<0 \implies -n \in \Bbb N$. Can't see how to do this given what we know already.

Is anyone else familiar with this text!? My first post. Not a terribly interesting question, would just like to see if I am missing something. Thanks for any help offered.

Comment: This must depend on the definition of $<$. [And, yet again, so sad to see that $0$ is not considered to be a natural number any more.]

Comment: When you have $m \in \mathbb N$ with $n < n+1 < m,$ you know that $m-n \in \mathbb N$ since $n \in S$, so by your step one, either $m-n = 1$ (contradiction) or $m-(n+1) \in \mathbb N$

Comment: Thanks for the help. I realised that by the way $\Bbb N$ was defined in the text (intersection of all successor subsets of $\Bbb R$), it's easy to prove that for every natural $n$, we have $n > 0$. Then the implication above beginning with $n<0$ is vacuously true, so no problems.